# Causes of NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to do the content management system. But when I clicked the button to activate/deactivate it gives me error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161.. What are the causes of this error?

**My view**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">

        <div class="x_content">
            <table class="table table-hover">

                <tr>

                    <th>
                        Original File Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Change File Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        File Extension
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Image
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($data as $file)
                <tr>

                    <th>{{ $file->original_filename}}</th> 
                    <th>{{ $file->rs_filename}}</th>
                    <th>{{ $file->file_extension}}</th>
                    <th><img src="/files/images/{{ $file->rs_filename }} "  width ="50px" height ="50px"></th>
                    <th>@if($file->category=="1"){{ "Laravel" }}@endif</th>
                    <th>@if($file->status=="0")<a href ="/activateImage/{{$file->id}}"><button class ="btn btn-primary" >{{"Activate"}} </button></a>@else <a href ="/deactivateImage/{{$file->id}}"><button class ="btn btn-primary" > {{ "Deactivate"}}@endif</button></a></th>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My routes**

```
Route::post('/activateImage{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@activateImage');
Route::post('/deactivateImage{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@deactivateImage');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use File;
use App\FileModel;
class LiveSearchLaravelController extends Controller 
{
  public function index()
  {
    $data = FileModel::all();
    return view('live_search_laravel.index',compact('data'));
  }
   public function activateImage($id)
  {
     $data = FileModel::find($id)->update('status', 1);
     return back();
  }  
  public function deactivateImage($id)
  {
     $data = FileModel::find($id)->update('status', 1);
     return back();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your route is `post` request and in your view, it's sending a `get` request, so you need to change your view content as:

```
<th>
    @if($file->status=="0")
        <form action="{{ url('activateImage', ['id' => $file->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
        </form>
    @else
        <form action="{{ url('deactivateImage', ['id' => $file->id]) }}" method="post">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Deactivate</button>
        </form>
    @endif
</th>
```

And your route should be as:

```
Route::post('activateImage/{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@activateImage');
Route::post('deactivateImage/{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@deactivateImage');
```

OR

The second option is to change your route to use `get` request as: *(which I would not recommend)*

```
Route::get('activateImage/{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@activateImage');
Route::get('deactivateImage/{id}', 'LiveSearchLaravelController@deactivateImage');
```

Then you can use it in `href` of `<a>` as:

```
{{ url('deactivateImage', ['id' => $file->id]) }}
```

Comment: In your each form add this {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: I tried to put <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" /> and now its working.. I encountered an error in my controller.. Is my controller correct?

Comment: In your activateImage, use 'where' insyead of 'wherein'. And you dont have deactivateImage method in your conter.

Comment: I think you have to change it as: `->update(['status' => 1])` and 0 for `deactivateImage` method.

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\gerald\Documents\git\sri-plugins\app\Http\Controllers\LiveSearchLaravelController.php on line 19

Comment: Change it in both methods.

Comment: Is this syntax correct? Because this is my preference, <form action="/activateImage/{{  $file->id}}" method="post">

Comment: For qualified path and for bindings. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url